# Treating NSCollectionView as an absolute grid

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscollectionview

My question is very simple: is NSCollectionView set up suitably for use as an absolute grid? Can I keep specific items in specific columns and rows, preventing item rearrangement on view resize and keeping everything where it belongs? Also, is user rearrangement (i.e. moving an item to an arbitrary blank space) feasible?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ?

Comment: No, I ended up writing a custom NSView subclass, which is working fine for me for now. I have to do some stuff manually but it's not so bad.

Comment: As a point of interest, did you consider using NSMatrix and if so, why did you end up sticking with NSCollection?